# How to replace part of a path in VSCode .json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use [Disasembly Explorer](https://github.com/dseight/vscode-disasexpl) to view my disassembled files. The extension wants to know where to search for `.s` files. The default setting is to look in the same directory as the source file:

```
"disasexpl.associations": {
        "**/*.c": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.s",
}
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
+ build
  + src1
    + foo.o
    + foo.s
  + src2
    + bar.o
    + bar.s
+ src1
  + foo.c
+ src2
  + bar.c
```

Basically the whole source directory structure is replicated in the `build` directory and contains the build artifacts.

How can I tell VSCode to take the relative path of a source file and prefix with `build/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the source file: https://github.com/dseight/vscode-disasexpl/blob/master/src/provider.ts

It supports more variables

```json
"disasexpl.associations": {
    "**/*.c": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${relativeFileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.s",
}
```